# Retrieve text from entry widget Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop, tkinter

So I know how to retrieve the text from a single entry widget using the get function but now I am trying to create multiple entry widgets at the same time using a for loop. How can I go back and retrieve the text from anyone of the entry widgets once the user types in them?

```
rows=11
for line in range(10):
    rows=rows+1
    widget = Tk.Entry(self.frame)
    widget.grid(row=rows, column=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
widgets = []

for i in range(11, 23):
    widgets.append(Tk.Entry(self.frame))
    widget[i-11].grid(row = i, column = 5)
```

Comment: I know how to get the value from one entry widget as I stated above. I am in a for loop now. If I wanted to retrieve the contents in say the 5th entry widgit how would I do so?

Comment: @userlincolndc: `widget[4].get()` (lists start counting at zero, so the 5th entry is at index 4)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all of your widget objects are being assigned to a reference, and with each next iteration of the loop are being unreferenced. A way to fix this is to create a list and add these widgets to the list:

```
entries = []
for line in range(10):
    rows = rows + 1
    widget = Tk.Entry(self.name)
    widget.grid(row = rows, column = 5)
    entries.append(widget)          # Add this line to your code
```

Now, to access a specific entrybox, you just find it in the array. So, for example, the second box will be found at `entries[1]` (because it is 0-based).

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem you're having is that you don't have any sort of data structure. Are you familiar with the `list` type?

```
rows=11
entries = [Tk.Entry(self.frame) for item in range(10)]
for item in entries:
    rows=rows+1
    item.grid(row=row, column=5)
```

This creates a `list` of `Entry` widgets, then goes through that `list` and `grid`s each one into a row (starting with `12`). You can access `list` items by index, e.g. `entries[0]` for the first `Entry`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you need the get() method, which is available to the Entry class. To get the value of your widget object, the code would look something like this:

```
myValue = widget.get()
```

Please note that, as others have mentioned, your "for" loop does not actually create 10 Entry objects. Since you keep reassigning your new Entry objects to the variable "widget", the old Entry object you created gets de-referenced. Instead of assigning each new Entry object to the variable "widget", append them to a list instead.

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit misleading. The loop does indeed create 10 Entry objects (widgets). What it doesn't do is create 10 _references_ to the Entry widgets.